# Настройка ipsec через double nat mikrotik

Tags: vpn, mikrotik, client

Имеется strongswan(v5.5.2) на линуксе в роли ответчика и микротик(ROS 6.40 stable), к которому подключен билайн 4g модем со статическим ip адресом, в роли инициатора. Так как модем раздаёт ip адрес микротику, то получается двойной нат(подсети 192.168.88.0/24 и 192.168.9.0/24). На модеме настроен dmz на микротик. Как в таком случае настроить ipsec site-to-site и возможно ли это сделать? И если объединить в бридж lte интерфейс и ether2-master, оно не сдохнет?